# Datastax Devcenter complains filter query fq as error

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

I tried following query to get distinct values in column 'name'

```
SELECT JSON name FROM program 
WHERE solr_query = '{"q":"*:*", "fq":"{!collapse field=name}"}';
```

Datastax devcenter complains this query as,

> Invalid DSE Search query syntax: Syntax Error, cannot parse :

When I tried executing the query inspite of error in devcenter, it returned results as expected.

[image]

**Now the question is,**

> Does datastax support or allow using fq (filter query) and !collapse?
>   or this is not a recommended/tested feature and hence devcenter is
>   complaining this as an error.

Answer (score 0):

Datastax said that its a bug,

> They have "logged bug HULK-1658 to have this addressed in a future
>   release of DataStax Studio"